# Find source for AWS RDS Connections

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

We have many RDS instances in our AWS account which we are not sure where they are getting used. We can see some active connections in some cases and wanted to find the source of those.

1. Is there a way I can find ips or something similar to know which hosts are trying to connect to this database?
2. Is there a way to get the credentials created originally for that AWS instances so that I could see what tables, schemas it contains, etc?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use [VPC Flow Logs - Amazon Virtual Private Cloud](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/flow-logs.html) on the Subnet containing the RDS DB instance.

Flow Logs can show the source/destination of traffic in the Subnet, and you could then figure out which EC2 instance has the source IP address.